# onclick defined text-var returns emptystring on log

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, ext.net

```
var listname=$(this).parents(".x-grid3-row-table").children(".x-grid3-cell-inner.x-grid3-col-1").text();
console.log(listname);
```

the console.log returns following:

```
(an empty string)
```

can you help me on why listname is empty? and could you also tell me how to pass listname as parameter to a server-side method in an Ext.Ajax.request?

this is the html-code coming from my generated page:

```
<table class="x-grid3-row-table>
  <tr>
   <td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-1 " tabindex="0" style="text-align: left;width: 265px;">
     <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-1" unselectable="on">foo_bar@domain.de</div>
   </td>
   <td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-2 x-grid3-cell-last " tabindex="0" style="width: 59px;">
      <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-2" unselectable="on">
        <span class="free">free</span>
       </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="x-grid3-row-body">
  <!-- 7 Elements Markup down, who all act wrapping for the following -->
    <div class="details">
      <!-- some other markup elements, who also contain data, but are not further interesting-->
      <td class="data"> foo bar detail data </td><!-- not of interest-->
      <td class="edit"><input value="edit" onclick="see function on top" type="button" /> </td>
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

target is to extract: **foo_bar@domain.de** and pass it to a server-method as parameter. the method is supposed to make a Window, but that's a different story.

the onclick call is from a expanded grid panel body, which is wrapped in a `table('.x-grid3-row-table')` with the given html-code.

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what your requirements are here, but you should not have to use some crazy css selector or crawling the dom to get this information. The data is available in the Store that is linked to the GridPanel. You can listen for any number of GridPanel events, such as row select or cell select|click. These event will include access to the Store.

Comment: @geoffrey.mcgill the problem is how to trigger these events from a html button in a row-expander template?

Comment: If you provide a reproducible Ext.NET sample demonstrating your scenario, I'm sure I'd be able to offer some suggestions. Maybe using a CommandColumn would be a better fit, see http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Commands/Row_Command/

Comment: @geoffrey.mcgill that is a much easier solution. until now i was thinking you'd have to add the buttons manually... thanks this helps a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space between class names in your children selector, however your markup suggests that both the class names are of same elements.

To select an element with more than one class names the selector should not have space between class names as `.classname1.className2`.

```
var listname=$(this).parents(".x-grid3-row-table").children(".x-grid3-cell-inner.x-grid3-col-1").text();
console.log(listname);
```

should work.

**Further clarification:**
If you have space between class names as in question it would mean that you are trying to select an element having `.x-grid3-col-1` class within `.x-grid3-cell-inner` class. Which is parent child relationship.

**Edit:**

If your button is in the next row you can use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) selector of JQuery with combination of using `tr` as parent selector rather than table.

`listname=$(this).parents("tr").prev().children(".x-grid3-cell-inner.x-grid3-col-1").text();`

Or if it is in same row then simply

`listname=$(this).parents("tr").children(".x-grid3-cell-inner.x-grid3-col-1").text();`

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it didn't fix yet... i am still trying to apply this fully

Comment: Would you like to extract all ".x-grid3-cell-inner.x-grid3-col-1" text values or just the one in the same row that was clicked? Removing the space should work with the html you provided so far.

Comment: @HMR the latter. i have included some additional markup whilst the whole markup would be somewhat too much. and if i had wanted to achieve the first, then i could have just selected `$(".x-grid3-col-1.x-grid3-cell-inner")`

Comment: @Vogel612 I have edited my answer as per my understanding of the question. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @FaisalSayed wonderful. that fixed it, but son't ask me why, because i do not know...

Answer (score 0):

There might be a cleaner way of doing this but I came up with this as your button click handler, it assumes that the text() your looking for is one table row up from the button.

```
    var $rows,button=this,i;
    $rows=$(".x-grid3-row-table tr");
    for(i=0;i<$rows.length;i++){
        // get the button of that row
        // not sure how to as your button is not
        // in a table row with the code you posted
        if($rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]===
          button){
            break;
        }
    }
    // I assume the button is in a row before the button
    console.log($($rows[i-1])
        .find(".x-grid3-cell-inner.x-grid3-col-1")
        .text()
```

Comment: sorry to tell you, but these are of course not the only rows, that was one row of an array of rows, each having such a "collection". the button is really not in the table-row and unfortunately i have no means to change the html-markup, thus your answer may be correct in some other problem, but here it is not working :(

Comment: I'd love to keep guessing how the buttons are related to the information in the table row but it might be easier if you just tell us.

Comment: damn i didn't include that to the markup... sorry. the buttons are the child of td with data's next sibling. but the row itself is that of a gridpanel and thus the only child with the combination of the two classes in the jquery children selector to the parent table x-grid3-row-table. this parent table is generated once per record in a certain database, which also includes further data, that are written to details